# How to compute complexity of a program that has framework library functions used

Tags: c#

```
public void ABC()
    {
         string inputString = "Programming C#";

         // Complexty = O(1) or O(n)  
            int length = inputString.Length;

        // Complexity = O(1) or O(n)
           bool found = inputString.Contains('#');
    }
```

---

The above program uses an inbuilt property to get length and contains function. The inbuilt function would be using loop to find a character in a string, but when we use the function directly, do we consider that function call as O(1)?

Thanks.

Comment: if you would consinder it O(1), then you could wrap everything within a function/class and simply state its O(1). Always keep the "calculation" cost in mind. For the str-length this can be 1, because the class internally cheats by keepting track of the size. But for a search this is most deffinatly N

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming `n` is the length of the string**, then you need to include the real complexity of all called functions.  Otherwise you won't obtain the correct result for your overall complexity.

Comment: I fear that the important part of your answer may not be evident to everyone reading it, so I try to highlight it: It depends on what `n` is. If `n` is the length of the string, you need to include it. If `n` is the number of elements in some list inside your class, you don't have to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure, but I guess it will be O(n) and not O(1).

There is a statistical way to determine it (nearly)... write a code to increase the string length programmatically, say 1st string is "p", second string - "pr", third string - "pro"... so on for a very large number of data (embed the '#' into the string if you also want to check the contains method)... log the begin and end time for each of the operation and plot the time response for the increasing string lengths...

The response should closely correspond to the complexity of whatever logic the program uses. Afterall, that is what complexity denotes... rate of growth of response time with respect to input size.

Comment: You'll need to come up with a chart representing the time response